# Executing a linux binary

Tags: linux, binary, execution

Well I've run across a very weird thing today and I don't know if its something to do with my OS or Virtualization. I've been running game-server binaries and they've always worked. A simple ./binary +parameters does the job pretty well but today I wanted to copy all the stuff to a VPS I recently bought. It was same as before, Debian ( XEN ). So on the new VPS when I do ./binary without any permissions, it would say permission denied. Now this is pretty much logical because I have to do a "chmod a+x" on the file for that to work but even after its done, it says "File Missing" although it runs perfectly well on the other machine. What could be wrong?

Comment: You're likely missing some library the binary depends on.  Anyway, the question is off-topic.

Comment: Run the file with strace as in strace binary.  You should see what file it is trying and failing to access.

Comment: More than offtopic I'd say he just doesn't know what he actually wants to ask...

Comment: Libraries are not missing. The strace output shows http://paste.ubuntu.com/1200916/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binary depends on some loadable library that is missing from your new server, it usually says so like this:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libfoobar.so.42: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but I'm not sure this is a general / standardized message.

You can check dynamic linking with the `ldd(1)` tool and look for unresolved libs (they are usually marked by `"=> not found"` )

On the other hand, maybe your binary is loading and starting without any problem, and it is simply checking for some files it wants and doesn't find them, and it is your binary (not the dynamic lib loader) that is printing that message. If you don't get any other message other than "File Missing" I suspect this is what's happening to you and you should go look your binary documentation (if it has any).

Comment: Okay what I'm actually doing is that the binary itself just needs a single library file so with ldconfig I've just set it to the dir where the lib resides. Works good on the previous server but not on this server so this might not be a missing library causing the issue. P.S : The message is "-bash: ./file: No such file or directory" I've also tried copying the lib to the default lib dir for no good.

Comment: Yours is not a library problem nor a binary executable problem, and reporting the exact output in your question would have made it obvious form the start. You have a problem in a bash script.

Comment: But then the output from your comment here is not coherent with the strace your pasted above. All in all, linux *is* starting whatever you're trying to run, the problem lies in your software so you should seek for help in its documentation/community/vendor/whatever. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah but why would the binary work on other Linux machines with exactly the same OS and libraries? Its actually just a Game Executable converted from a Windows version of the game so there are no documentations sadly.

Comment: I don't know, but I do know it is nothing related to this question. Comments are not for follow-up questions, please see the FAQ.